# Linear Algebra: How to notate vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

In my paper, I want to write that the $(x,y)$ coordinate could be transformed into a $(u,v)$ coordinate.

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=P\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$$

I would like to say this is $x=Py$, where $P$ denotes the transformation matrix.

However, the $x$ in $x=Py$ is $(x,y)$, and the $y$ is $(u,v)$. And that would be very confusing for the reader.

What would be better letters to replace $x,y$ in the $x=Py$ equation?

---

Certaily, I can use any letter. But I think we should try to use the more conventional ones, just like we tend to use $x$ when solving equations.

Comment: I don't understand what your asking: just suggestions on which letters to use?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD exactly, what to use insteand of `x=Py`?, the `x` and `y` are already used in the vector of the left hand side of the equation. Using them to denote vectors is a bit confusing.

Comment: Err, I guess you could name the vectors $x,y$ and their coordinates $x_1,x_2$, idem for $y$?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD. And that is the problem, becuase I want to `x,y` and `u,v` for coordinates. This is because they correspondes to the two coordinate systems thta I used. So I'm asking what other letter could use instead of the vector `x, y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use $\mathbf r = (x,y)$, because a point $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$ can be thought of as a vector, i.e., an arrow pointing $r$adially away from the origin. In physics it's common to write boldface (i.e., $\mathbf r$) for vectors and italic (i.e., $r$) for their corresponding lengths, and we may think of the length $r$ of $\mathbf r = (x,y)$ as the radius of a circle. This plays nicely with polar coordinates.

As for $(u,v)$, I don't have a great answer... maybe an equation like $\mathbf r = P \mathbf r'$ would do well at showing that $\mathbf r'$ is a new/transformed/(primed) version of $\mathbf r$. Hence $(u, v) = \mathbf r'$.

Comment: This is a good expression, I like this.

Answer (score 3):

Some suggestions that are commonly used:

$\vec{a}$
$\hat{a}$
$\mathbf{a}$

There are many stories of where notation conventions were invented because of ease of putting it on a typewriter. Like $\lambda$ for lambda calculus even though that's not how it appears in the handwritten versions. But now take advantage of your vast typesetting capabilities and you don't have to give different letters; you can use various modifiers like hats and tildes.

Answer (score 2):

It might be simplest to write
$$
x=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix}\qquad u=\begin{bmatrix}u_1\\u_2\end{bmatrix}\qquad x=Pu\quad.
$$

Comment: The problem is that, I want to keep `x, y` and `u,v `. Because they represent the name of the axis of coordinate systems that I used.

Comment: Then I’d use capitals: $X$ and $U$ for the vectors. Or maybe $Z$ and $W$. Maybe even l.c., $z$ and $w$.